# How to create a postfix-like server with python smtpd

Tags: python, postfix-mta, smtpd

About the python smtpd library, I try to override the process_message method, but when I try to connect to it with client and send message to, say a gmail account, it just print the message out on console, but I want it actually to send out the message like postfix in local machine. How should I achieve this?

I google smtpd, but not much useful message to find

```
import smtpd
import asyncore

class CustomSMTPServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):

    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data, **kwargs):
        print('Receiving message from:', peer)
        print('Message addressed from:', mailfrom)
        print('Message addressed to  :', rcpttos)
        print('Message length        :', len(data))
        return

server = CustomSMTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 1025), None)

asyncore.loop()
```

Comment: Are you trying to send an email or receive an email? The code above is to receive a message.

Comment: Send an email, but without using smtplib to connect and authenticate to other smtp servers such as gmail, I want this code itself be an smtp server, when it receive the email it can transfer it to other smtp server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citing [Robert Putt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54185041/2765752), you're going to struggle with deliverability. You're best solution would be to locally host an SMTP server (of course the supreme solution would be to use [AmazonSES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) or an API like [MailGun](https://www.mailgun.com/)). [DigialOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) has a good tutorial here. You can then use the below Python code to send out an email.

```py
import smtplib

sender = 'no_reply@mydomain.com'
receivers = ['person@otherdomain.com']

message = """From: No Reply <no_reply@mydomain.com>
To: Person <person@otherdomain.com>
Subject: Test Email

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
    print("Successfully sent email")
except SMTPException:
    print("Error: unable to send email")
```

Hopefully this helps!